# Filtering SQL results using child records and parent record dates

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a festival with dates

- start: 2021-02-01
- end: 2021-02-28

and I have events with FINAL dates

- event1: 2021-01-01 - 2021-01-10
- event2: 2021-01-25 - 2021-02-05
- event3: 2021-02-15 - 2021-02-16
- event4: 2021-02-27 - 2021-03-01
- event5: 2021-03-01 - 2021-03-05

the festival and it's events are all represented in a DB table using versioning as follows

**table1**

| uuid | eventId | type | name | startDate | endDate | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 123 | festival | 'my festival' | '2020-06-01' | '2020-06-30' | 1 |
| abce | 123 | festival | 'my festival' | '2020-12-01' | '2020-12-31' | 2 |
| abcf | 123 | festival | 'my festival' | '2021-02-01' | '2021-02-28' | 3 |
| abcg | 124 | event | 'event1' | '2020-01-01' | '2020-01-10' | 1 |
| abch | 124 | event | 'event1' | '2021-01-02' | '2021-01-10' | 2 |
| abci | 125 | event | 'event2' | '2021-01-01' | '2021-01-02' | 1 |
| abcg | 125 | event | 'event2' | '2021-01-25' | '2021-02-05' | 2 |
| abck | 126 | event | 'event3' | '2021-02-02' | '2021-02-03' | 1 |
| abcl | 126 | event | 'event3' | '2021-02-15' | '2021-02-16' | 2 |
| abcm | 127 | event | 'event4' | '2021-02-20' | '2021-03-01' | 1 |
| abco | 127 | event | 'event4' | '2021-02-27' | '2021-03-01' | 2 |
| abco | 128 | event | 'event5' | '2021-02-01' | '2021-02-05' | 1 |
| abcq | 128 | event | 'event5' | '2021-03-15' | '2021-03-16' | 2 |
| abcr | 129 | festival | 'festival2' | '2021-03-29' | '2021-04-03' | 1 |
| abcs | 130 | event | 'event6' | '2021-04-02' | '2021-04-02' | 1 |

From this table I want to get all records using specific dates (eg. 3 first months of 2021) and filter out the events that are not under any festival

I want the results to include event2, event3 and event4

- event2: end time is after festival start
- event4: start time is before festival end

What I have up to now is big, confusing and does not get my results :(

```
SET @exportStart='2021-01-01';
SET @exportEnd='2021-03-31';

SELECT ta1.eventId, ta1.type, ta1.name, ta1.startDate, ta1.endDate, ta1.version
FROM table1 ta1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT eventId, MAX(`version`) AS recentVersion
        from table1
        group by eventId 
    ) TT ON TT.eventId = ta1.eventId and ta1.`version` = TT.recentVersion   
WHERE (ta1.startDate BETWEEN @exportStart AND @exportEnd) 
        OR (ta1.endDate BETWEEN @exportStart AND @exportEnd) 
        OR (ta1.startDate < @exportStart AND ta1.endDate > @exportEnd )
    AND ta1.eventId NOT IN (
        -- get ids of events that are not under festivals
        SELECT ta2.eventId 
        FROM table1 ta2
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT eventId, MAX(`version`) AS recentVersion 
            from table1 
            group by eventId 
        ) ZZ ON ta2.eventId = ZZ.eventId and ta2.`version` = ZZ.recentVersion           
        LEFT JOIN (
            -- get only festivals 
            SELECT ta3.* 
            FROM table1 ta3 
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT eventId, MAX(`version`) AS recentVersion 
                from table1 
                group by eventId 
            ) XX ON ta3.eventId = re3.eventId and ta3.`version` = XX.recentVersion  
            WHERE type = 'festival'
                AND (
                    (startDate BETWEEN @exportStart AND @exportEnd)
                    OR (endDate BETWEEN @exportStart AND @exportEnd) 
                    OR (startDate < @exportStart AND endDate > @exportEnd)
                )
        ) FESTDATES on FESTDATES.eventId = ta2.eventId
        WHERE ( 
            (startDate BETWEEN @exportStart AND @exportEnd)
            OR (endDate BETWEEN @exportStart AND @exportEnd)
            OR (startDate < @exportStart AND endDate > @exportEnd )
        )
        AND (
            -- filter events not under festivals // does not work
            ta2.type != 'festival' 
            AND (
                (ta2.startDate > FESTDATES.endDate)
                OR (ta2.endDate < FESTDATES.startDate)
            )
        )
);
```

Edit for Gordon's questions

1. If an event has dates between the festival (or ends after festival starts, or starts before festival ends) then it is under a festival.
2. Versioning is based on edits of each record. We don't edit the specific record, we create a new version with the new data/dates.

Comment: Please explain how you determine if an event is "under a festival".  And what do "version"s mean.

Comment: a mysql date is yyyy-mm-dd eve4rything else needs to be converted,what take too much tme

Comment: just changed the format of the dates for better clarity

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS festivals;
CREATE TABLE festivals
(festival_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,festival_name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
,start_date DATE NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO festivals VALUES
(1,'festival1','2020-06-01','2020-06-30'),
(2,'festival2','2020-12-01','2020-12-31'),
(3,'festival3','2021-02-01','2021-02-28');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
CREATE TABLE events
(event_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,event_name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
,start_date DATE NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO events VALUES
(101,'event1','20210101','20210110'),
(102,'event2','20210125','20210205'),
(103,'event3','20210215','20210216'),
(104,'event4','20210227','20210301'),
(105,'event5','20210301','20210305');
```

...

```
 SELECT e.* 
   FROM events e 
   LEFT 
   JOIN festivals f 
     ON f.start_date <= e.end_date 
    AND f.end_date > e.start_date 
  WHERE f.festival_id IS NULL;
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| event_id | event_name | start_date | end_date   |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|      101 | event1     | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-10 |
|      105 | event5     | 2021-03-01 | 2021-03-05 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Yes it will be a solution when there will be a rewrite of the entire application. For now a backend implementation is based on the specific DB and some million records, which cannot change in a single day.

Answer (score 0):

This should do as you wanted.

Besides some combined indexes you can add a Where clause to select the festivals you want.

I selected a WEEK as Limit for the events, but that must be finetuned

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `uuid` VARCHAR(4),
>   `eventId` INTEGER,
>   `type` VARCHAR(8),
>   `name` VARCHAR(13),
>   `startDate` date,
>   `endDate` date,
>   `version` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`uuid`, `eventId`, `type`, `name`, `startDate`, `endDate`, `version`)
> VALUES
>   ('abcd', '123', 'festival', 'my festival', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-30', '1'),
>   ('abce', '123', 'festival', 'my festival', '2020-12-01', '2020-12-31', '2'),
>   ('abcf', '123', 'festival', 'my festival', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28', '3'),
>   ('abcg', '124', 'event', 'event1', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-10', '1'),
>   ('abch', '124', 'event', 'event1', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-10', '2'),
>   ('abci', '125', 'event', 'event2', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '1'),
>   ('abcg', '125', 'event', 'event2', '2021-01-25', '2021-02-05', '2'),
>   ('abck', '126', 'event', 'event3', '2021-02-02', '2021-02-03', '1'),
>   ('abcl', '126', 'event', 'event3', '2021-02-15', '2021-02-16', '2'),
>   ('abcm', '127', 'event', 'event4', '2021-02-20', '2021-03-01', '1'),
>   ('abco', '127', 'event', 'event4', '2021-02-27', '2021-03-01', '2'),
>   ('abco', '128', 'event', 'event5', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-05', '1'),
>   ('abcq', '128', 'event', 'event5', '2021-03-15', '2021-03-16', '2'),
>   ('abcr', '129', 'festival', 'festival2', '2021-03-29', '2021-04-03', '1'),
>   ('abcs', '130', 'event', 'event6', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-02', '1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> f.`name`,f.`startDate`,f.`endDate`,e.`name`,e.`startDate`,e.`endDate`
> FROM (SELECT t1.*  
> FROm table1 t1 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `eventId`, MAX(`version`) maxversion FROM table1 GROUP BY `eventId`) t2 
> ON t1.`eventId` = t2.`eventId` AND t1.`version` = t2.maxversion
> WHERE `type` = 'festival') f
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT t1.*  
> FROm table1 t1 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `eventId`, MAX(`version`) maxversion FROM table1 GROUP BY `eventId`) t2 
> ON t1.`eventId` = t2.`eventId` AND t1.`version` = t2.maxversion
> WHERE `type` = 'event') e 
> ON  e.`startDate` BETWEEN f.`startDate`  -  INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND f.`endDate`  +  INTERVAL  1 WEEK
> AND e.`endDate` BETWEEN f.`startDate`  AND f.`endDate`  +  INTERVAL  1 WEEK
> ```
>
> ```
> name        | startDate  | endDate    | name   | startDate  | endDate   
> :---------- | :--------- | :--------- | :----- | :--------- | :---------
> my festival | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 | event2 | 2021-01-25 | 2021-02-05
> my festival | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 | event3 | 2021-02-15 | 2021-02-16
> my festival | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 | event4 | 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-01
> festival2   | 2021-03-29 | 2021-04-03 | event6 | 2021-04-02 | 2021-04-02
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.*  
> FROm table1 t1 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `eventId`, MAX(`version`) maxversion FROM table1 GROUP BY `eventId`) t2 
> ON t1.`eventId` = t2.`eventId` AND t1.`version` = t2.maxversion
> WHERE `type` = 'festival'
> ```
>
> ```
> uuid | eventId | type     | name        | startDate  | endDate    | version
> :--- | ------: | :------- | :---------- | :--------- | :--------- | ------:
> abcf |     123 | festival | my festival | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-28 |       3
> abcr |     129 | festival | festival2   | 2021-03-29 | 2021-04-03 |       1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *  
> FROm table1 t1 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `eventId`, MAX(`version`) maxversion FROM table1 GROUP BY `eventId`) t2 
> ON t1.`eventId` = t2.`eventId` AND t1.`version` = t2.maxversion
> WHERE `type` = 'event'
> ```
>
> ```
> uuid | eventId | type  | name   | startDate  | endDate    | version | eventId | maxversion
> :--- | ------: | :---- | :----- | :--------- | :--------- | ------: | ------: | ---------:
> abch |     124 | event | event1 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-10 |       2 |     124 |          2
> abcg |     125 | event | event2 | 2021-01-25 | 2021-02-05 |       2 |     125 |          2
> abcl |     126 | event | event3 | 2021-02-15 | 2021-02-16 |       2 |     126 |          2
> abco |     127 | event | event4 | 2021-02-27 | 2021-03-01 |       2 |     127 |          2
> abcq |     128 | event | event5 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-16 |       2 |     128 |          2
> abcs |     130 | event | event6 | 2021-04-02 | 2021-04-02 |       1 |     130 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18379803409c630c3740656a755f8727)*